# Node attachment position

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to create solutions to a matching type question which will require me to draw lines between boxes. I've been trying to use `tikzpicture` to do this:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!0, 
text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em] 
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node [block] (1) {1};
\node [block, below of=1, node distance=1cm] (2) {2};
\node [block, below of=2, node distance=1cm] (3) {3};
\node [block, below of=3, node distance=1cm] (4) {4};

\node [block, right of=1, node distance=11cm] (Four) {Four};
\node [block, right of=2, node distance=11cm] (Three) {Three};
\node [block, right of=3, node distance=11cm] (One) {One};
\node [block, right of=4, node distance=11cm] (Two) {Two};

\path [line] (1) --  (One);
\path [line] (2) -- (Two);
\path [line] (3) -- (Three);
\path [line] (4) -- (Four); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this produces the following which is quite ugly: [image]

I would like to produce something like this where the arrows start from the middle of the right edge of the box and goes to the middle of the left edge of the box: 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `matrix` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\tikzset{block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!0,
            text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
          line/.style  = {draw, -latex'}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    row sep=1cm, column sep=2cm, nodes={block},    %% adjust row and column sep
  ]{
    1 & Four\\
    2 & Three \\
    3 & One \\
    4 & Two \\
  };
  \draw[line](m-1-1.east) -- (m-3-2.west); 
  \draw[line](m-2-1.east) -- (m-4-2.west); 
  \draw[line](m-3-1.east) -- (m-2-2.west); 
  \draw[line](m-4-1.east) -- (m-1-2.west);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]